# Dynamically add ordered number to each object in Paginated response from Django Rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm currently getting a standard paginated response using Django REST framework, however I need to add a number to each object response in the order it is retrieved. 1,2,3,4,5 etc. It must be calculated each time dynamically if new results are added and retrieved by the user. It would go from this:

```
{
"next": "http://localhost:8000/api/home/?page=2",
"previous": null,
"count": 105,
"results": [
    {
        "title": "example1",
        "description": "foobar1",
    },
    {
        "title": "example2",
        "description": "",
    },
    ...
]
```

to looking like this:

```
{
"next": "http://localhost:8000/api/home/?page=2",
"previous": null,
"count": 105,
"results": [
    {
        "key": 1,
        "title": "example1",
        "description": "foobar1",
    },
    {
        "key": 2,
        "title": "example2",
        "description": "",
    },
    ...
]
```

This would also include the next page in the paginated response, e.g. 21, 22, 23, 24. If a user then refreshes the page and new data is found and retrieved it would recalculate and add key numbers again. How would one go about this?
Thanks!

Comment: The response data is already ordered before being returned. Why do you need an extra field to specify the order when the index is already enough? The index/position of each object in the result gives the same result as what you are looking for

Comment: @Ken4scholars thanks that helped. I needed the index for the frontend, depending on which particular number index it was. Reactjs actually holds an index of the mapped list so I've used that.